# Como poner fondo de color a un section

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

¿Cómo puedo hacer que todo `section` esté de un solo color?

Este es mi código:

```html
<section class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-10" style="background: #432345">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><br>Sala de Cómputo</br>
      ITO</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <span id="ip_field"></span>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
```

*Estoy tratando de hacer que section tenga un fondo de color en específico pero lo que tengo dentro de section no toman ese color*

[image: pongo el fondo de un color pero las demás etiquetas están encimadas]

Comment: como puedo hacer que todo section esté de un solo color ???

Comment: Pedro, debes redactar una buena pregunta. Lee: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. y edita la pregunta.

Comment: los bg- de bootstrap no te sirven?

Comment: He tratado pero tampoco, me sigue apareciendo lo mismo

Comment: Ya pude amigo, la razón es que ya estaba utilizando un bg (bg-light) por eso no podía apenas me di cuenta gracias.

Comment: No me había dado cuenta , la razón es que ya estaba utilizando un bg (bg-light) por eso no podía

Answer (score 0):

Añade esto a tu css

```
section > * {
    background: #432345;
}
```

ya si quieres a un solo section en especifico agrega una clase al section y luego haces referencia

```
section.clase > * {
    background: #432345;
}
```

Comment: No me muestran los cambios, lo hay dentro de section no cambian de color

Answer (score 0):

Como te mencionan arriba puedes crear una clase y posteriormente hacer referencia a ella dentro de tu css, aunque si esto no te resulta también puedes intentar utilizando el atributo id en el section al que quieres dar estilo. Esto sería así, revisa el id="section-style" del html:

```
        <section class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-10" id="section-style">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><br>Sala de Cómputo</br>
          ITO</a>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">         
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <span id="ip_field"></span>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

y en css sería algo como esto:

```
#section-style{
    background-color: #432345;
    }
```

Comment: No me funciona amigo, lo que tengo dentro de section sigue sin ponerse de ese color.

Comment: Puedes utilizar los selectores con hijos, por ejemplo para el caso del nav:                          
         #section-style > nav{
          background-color: #432345;
        }                                                                                                                       y despues puedes seguir con los demas elementos si quieres por ejemplo para el div                                                                                                                                  
         #section-style > nav{
          background-color: #432345;
        }